# Check if domain is available for purchase - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way that I check if a certain domain is available for purchase?
If there is any library out there that will do this?

THanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take a look at: http://www.internetbs.net/ResellerRegistrarDomainNameAPI/api/01_domain_related/01_domain_check
Its pretty straight forward to use:

```
https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=testapi&Password=testpass&Domain=example.com
```

and the result would be:

```
transactid=e504cdbf00e7821e954f0f5a65249ff0
status=UNAVAILABLE
domain=example.com
minregperiod=1Y
maxregperiod=10Y
registrarlockallowed=YES
privatewhoisallowed=YES
realtimeregistration=YES
```

Comment: +1 This looks like the public API I thought wouldn't exist...

Comment: Yep, i have not tested it, but it looks pretty good and simple to use, Long Live to RESTful services..

Comment: This looks great thanks for all the answers guys

Comment: This doesn't always work (possibly deliberately due to the 'testapi' key) - try 'yumyar.com' - this comes out as available when it's actually registered.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question: [Who provides a WHOIS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api)

..Yet another Google search that leads *back* to SO...

Comment: Unfortunately, whois isn't a reliable indicator of whether a domain is available.

Comment: @RickNZ: True, it looks like Omar's answer below is a good public API for domain searches.

Comment: i agree whois wont be that reliable

Answer (score 1):

Get a windows build of the common linux whois client or something similar. Do a system call to run that and parse its output.

Kind of kludgy but it is easy and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need C# to do this?  can't you do a WHOIS or a grep?

Comment: whois runs on Windows too (along with dig and host)

Comment: right so use one or the other..not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Your answer was really more of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an c# application using [Watin Libarary](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) and set the application go to  a site like (www.register.com or ... ) and get the result you can set the application to read from a list of your domain names and get the results .