# how tocheck domain availble or not using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How to check domain availability in C#?

Can you tell me some free Domain availability checker web api?
code I tried but its giving error saying server not found

```
 string url = "https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=test123i&Password=test123&Domain=" + chkchar[0] +"." + chkchar[1];
```

Comment: You could use this site: http://whois.domaintools.com/[Yourdomain]

Comment: You can use "internet.bs" aspi for this purpose.

See this [How check domain status][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868631/check-if-domain-is-available-for-purchase-c-sharp

Comment: https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=testapi&Password=testpass&Domain=google.com

giving error saying - server not found